# ODBC connection failure in MS Access

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2007

I have a problem with my ODBC connection in MS Access.

Here's the strange part,we have a shared MS Access Database and everything work so fine in the other computer but not in mine. As I check my MSJET version, its 4.0.9511.0. Does it matters?

This happens when I run one of the queries.

How am I going to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the Access DB is being opened for 'Shared' access rather than exclusive? It might be that the other computer has it open in Exclusive mode and is hence locking you out.

Comment: I bet this is not about if the DB is shared or not because I tried to copy the DB in my local, then same error prompts.

Comment: Where is the code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Some ODBC connections pass the username of the active windows user, and if that is the case, one user may be authorized while the user you copied it to may not be.  Try copying the ODBC connection string up so we can see what it looks like.